# How to load the value of attributes from property files into INSTANCES OF classes

Tags: java, properties, java-7

I have a software that should read some properties file at each start and construct the classes from those:

```
name = John
surname = Smith
```

The class person will have then

```
public class Person{
    private final String name; 
    private final String surname;
}
```

Is there some magic method or class which I don't know about which will let me do something like:

```
loadedPersonProperties.createClass(Person)
```

? English is not my first language and I cannot understand if I am looking for the wrong words or I simply have to do such a constructor myself.
Thank you.

EDIT:added INSTANCES OF, as the .java file generation is not necessary

Comment: You're looking for something similar to a JSON parser, but I don't think you'll find one simply because Java is statically typed.  I've always written parsers myself, so I'd be interested if there is a lightweight framework out there that can do this.

Comment: Are the property files predefined, or can you change them? If you change them to json it's relatively easy

Comment: I can choose how to store them, as long as the generation doesn't take too much effort either. JSON surely will have some supporting library

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the Java Properties class and corresponding .properties files.

Comment: @tobi6 That is what I am trying to do, but suppose I have a huge property file. Is there a method to immediately load the properties into the file attributes? Like: `MyClass class = new MyClass.generateFromProperty(properties)? `

Comment: You still need to write a small wrapper or static function which gets the values out of the properties and sets it to a new class.

Comment: So there is no built in method? I couldn't find any. If you are sure this is the answer, please DO answer, as I will mark it.

Comment: You might look at [Template-Based Code Generation with Apache Velocity, ](http://archive.oreilly.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/05/05/cg-vel1.html).

Comment: This looks useful, but it's CODE generation, not instance. I will use the approach of having a static factory. Thank you